# LinearGradient for path SVG

Tags: path, svg, linear-gradients

I need to fill a path which is created dynamically using javascript. I've created a gradient for that and used that to fill my path, but nothing happened. What's wrong with my code?

```
$('svg').prepend('<defs id="gradient"></defs>');
$('#gradient').append('<linearGradient id="yellow" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">  </linearGradient>');
$('#yellow').append('<stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1" /> <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />');
$('g:nth-child(2n+1) path').attr('fill','url(#gradient)');`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your fill points to a defs element and not the linearGradient. The id="gradient" should be on the linearGradient element - or alternatively make the fill url(#yellow)